# How does gear reduction affect a stepper motor's holding torque?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, torque, stepper-motor

I'm new to mechanical engineering, gears, and motors. Coming from a software/hardware background, I am trying to understand how to leverage gear reduction to maximize the torque output of a stepper motor for an equatorial mount. The speed can be very slow so I would like to focus on maximizing torque for a heavy payload.

By my understanding, the output torque is the product of the input torque and the gear ratio. Is this the same for the "holding torque" of a gear system? Is the output holding torque the product of the input holding torque and the gear ratio?

Comment: Yes, plus stiction and friction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the holding torque goes up proportionally with the gear ratio. Plus the friction of the gear train, and any other seals, bearings along the gear train that add friction.